# Simple python script will not run in Visual Studio 2017

Tags: python, visual-studio

I've just now installed visual studio 2017 for python coding. I'm pretty new to python. I was messing around with python in visual studio, and on my first .py file I've tried to create, it will not run in visual studio.

Opening up the .py in IDLE, it runs fine and works perfectly. In visual studio, a dialog pops up saying "press any key to continue..." and then closes. Debug output shows:

```
The thread 0x1 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The program 'python.exe' has exited with code 0 (0x0).
```

The program would run in visual studio fine at first but randomly stopped, and after a reinstall of visual it still won't run.

The code for my program is:

```py
def calculateMean(numbers):
    sum = 0
    for i in numbers:
        sum += numbers
    mean = sum / len(i)
    return mean
def quadraticFormula(a,b,c):
    numeratorRoot = ((b**2)-(4*a*c))**(1/2)
    firstResult = ((b*-1)+numeratorRoot)/(2*a)
    secondResult = ((b*-1)-numeratorRoot)/(2*a)
    return firstResult,secondResult

if __name__ == "__main__":
    first = int(input("pick a: "))
    second = int(input("pick b: "))
    third = int(input("pick c: "))
    result1,result2 = quadraticFormula(first,second,third)
    print("The results are: R1={0} R2={1}".format(result1,result2))
```

Comment: Going to Debug and selecting "Execute file in python interactive" properly runs down in the output area. Still don't know why running it normally doesn't work